# svelte css ordering is not picking up global as last to apply

Tags: css, svelte

my global css file is being overwritten by bootstrap. i have tried ordering them differently but it keeps on loading bootstrap css last and applying that last so I have to use !important in my css for the styles to work

here is my example index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/build/bundle.css'>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>
</head>
```

my rollup config file

```
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import css from 'rollup-plugin-css-only';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

function serve() {
    let server;

    function toExit() {
        if (server) server.kill(0);
    }

    return {
        writeBundle() {
            if (server) return;
            server = require('child_process').spawn('npm', ['run', 'start', '--', '--dev'], {
                stdio: ['ignore', 'inherit', 'inherit'],
                shell: true
            });

            process.on('SIGTERM', toExit);
            process.on('exit', toExit);
        }
    };
}

export default {
    input: 'src/main.ts',
    output: {
        sourcemap: !production,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/build/bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ 
                sourceMap: !production,
                // defaults: {
                //  style: 'scss'
                //   },
                postcss: {
                    plugins: [
                    //  require("tailwindcss"), 
                     require("autoprefixer"),
                    ],
                  },
            }),
            compilerOptions: {
                // enable run-time checks when not in production
                dev: !production
            },
            emitCss: true,
        }),
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),

        // If you have external dependencies installed from
        // npm, you'll most likely need these plugins. In
        // some cases you'll need additional configuration -
        // consult the documentation for details:
        // https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: ['svelte']
        }),
        commonjs(),
        typescript({
            sourceMap: !production,
            inlineSources: !production
        }),
        json(),
        // In dev mode, call `npm run start` once
        // the bundle has been generated
        !production && serve(),

        // Watch the `public` directory and refresh the
        // browser on changes when not in production
        !production && livereload('public'),

        // If we're building for production (npm run build
        // instead of npm run dev), minify
        production && terser()
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false
    }
};
```

Comment: Look how css works, especially specifity.

Comment: bootstrap is taking precedence over global and bundle file which is not making sense why.

Comment: Because it has higher specifity. Look up on how css works, especially the C (cascade) part of CSS.